# Invalid behavior of C# code while using IList in Unity3d on iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have found a strange behavior in my Unity3D project written in C# and built for iPhone.
*Sometimes* IList objects (objects of types which implement IList interface) lose information about elements types. During my research I figured out that it occurs when typecast to IList had a place (f.e. from **ArrayList** to **IList**) and **ToString()** method was called.

Here is a simple test method I called from **Start()** method of my script.

```
public void IListToStringTest() {
  ConsolePrintln("---\nIListToStringTest");
  IList list = new ArrayList(); // <-- ARRAYLIST IS TYPECASTED TO ILIST

  list.Add(1);

  ConsolePrintln("Before \"listString = list.ToString()\"");

  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());

  string listString = list.ToString();

  ConsolePrintln("After \"listString = list.ToString()\"");

  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString()); // <-- TYPE INFO IS ALREADY LOST
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0] = " + list[0].ToString());
  ConsolePrintln("list[0].GetType().ToString() = " + list[0].GetType().ToString());

  ConsolePrintln("listString = " + listString);

  int intFromList = (int)list[0]; // <-- InvalidCastException IS THROWN HERE

  ConsolePrintln("intFromList = " + intFromList);
}
```

And here is an output:

```
---
IListToStringTest
Before "listString = list.ToString()"
list[0] = 1
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.Int32
list[0] = 1
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.Int32
list[0] = 1
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.Int32
After "listString = list.ToString()"
list[0] = System.Collections.ArrayList
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.String
list[0] = System.Collections.ArrayList
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.String
list[0] = System.Collections.ArrayList
list[0].GetType().ToString() = System.String
listString = System.Collections.ArrayList
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at PPSSerializingTest.IListToStringTest () [0x001ba] in /Users/vlad/Projects/Unity/PPSSerializingTest/Assets/PPSSerializingTest.cs:171
  at PPSSerializingTest.Start () [0x00000] in /Users/vlad/Projects/Unity/PPSSerializingTest/Assets/PPSSerializingTest.cs:16
```

As you can see after **list.ToString()** was called information about element was lost.

Note, that this issue is not reproduced every time. I reproduced it on iPhone 4s (iOS 5.01) after 4 or more launches from Xcode (without rebuilding it from Unity).
I'm using Unity 3.5.0b6, license type: Unity, iPhone, Android.

Is there any idea why this may happen?

Thanks in advance!

PS* I have opened another thread about issue that can be related to this: [C# List<object> to IList cast bug in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929388/c-sharp-listobject-to-ilist-cast-bug-in-unity3d-monotouch)

Comment: +1 for the detailed description. Quick test revealed it's not reproducible on my machine. I know this is quite annoying. What is done inside of your ConsolePrintln method?

Comment: FWIW this works in both Mono and MonoTouch

Comment: ConsolePrintln is quite simple and contains only `UnityEngine.Debug.Log(text);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can see.  This is exactly the behavior that should happen.

> string listString = list.ToString();

This converts the collection which is an `IList` to a `string` so the string value of **liststring** would be `string` value equal to **System.Collections.IList** if I am not mistaken.

You are basically doing `Type.ToString()` on that line.  As to the reason it appears the type in the ArrayList is changing, I honestly cannot explain that, I suspect something non-sinister is going on.

> string listString = list.ToString();

could easily become

> string listString = list[0].ToString();

That would at least set the value of `liststring` to the first element of the `ArrayList` **list**